# Нужна ли запятая: "...наш земляк Герой Советского Союза Шолыгин"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

А если предложение:

> На фотографии изображен наш земляк Герой Советского Союза Шолыгин.

Здесь запятая или тире нужны после "земляк"? Или все зависит от интонации автора?

Answer (score 1):

В таком случае меня учили рассуждать так: земляк - обязательно Герой Советского Союза? А Герой - обязательно земляк? Нет! Поэтому запятая не нужна

Answer (score 1):

Все же знак лучше поставить. Пожалуй, я бы поставил тире. От контекста еще зависит, конечно.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна, а вот тире можно поставить, если приложению необходимо придать пояснительный характер. Обычно  после приложения  можно поставить слова: а именно, то есть. В вашем примере по смыслу такие слова можно поставить.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Принимаю все.